# HighStocks volume chart labels showing values in millions/thousands

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I have a candlestick and volume series chart. Candlestick series has values

```
[0: 114652800,1: 171.15, 2: 171.35, 3: 170.65, 4: 170.65]
```

And volume chart values

```
 [0:114652800, 1:218]
```

(gave a dataset for each series getting from database).

Now the problem is when I want to show both the series on a single yAxis, the volume series is missing. Then I tried to use two yAxis, then the volume data are showing in millions.
so I am confused as after the console log it shows values [0:114652800, 1:218]. But plotting shows labels in millions. I use vue highcharts. Please help.

Comment: Please post a working example of highchart with the problem.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?